# How to access website on docker container(apache server) from other network?

Tags: docker, apache, networking

Hello sorry for stupid question.. But i have googled it for a week and still can't find the answer.

Currently I'm using Virtualbox for ubuntu server 18.04 and I have installed docker on it. I have run docker apache server by using `sudo docker pull httpd` and `sudo docker run -t --name apache -p 8080:80 httpd`

And there is the problem. I can show the website by using `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` but i can't access from the other network or other machine in different network.

For instance my virtualbox's ip address is 1.1.1.1 and host pc which is window is 2.2.2.2.

When i ping to each other it all works. But when i try to access 1.1.1.1:8080 from host pc i can't access

What should i check or do to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For "1.1.1.1:8080" access on the host- Try opening TCP traffic on port 8080 of your virtual machine with firewall-cmd or an equivalent Ubuntu utility.  "1.1.1.1:8080" should then become available on your host server.

For "2.2.2.2:XXXX" access from other devices on your home network(s)- You might need to both route the port of your VM to a port of your host (unless you have a pass-through NIC configured on the VM) on the VM manager plus open an additional firewall on your host server on the host port you've mapped to for access by other devices on your home network.  After those steps on the host port "2.2.2.2:XXXX" should be the web server IP accessible by any device on your network(s).

For PUBLIC_IP:PUBLIC_PORT access from outside networks (external to your modem and available to the world)- IPs on your home networks can't be accessed from other networks. Access from other devices on your network is controlled by your firewall on your OS.  Access from outside networks is controlled by port forwarding on your modem.  I don't recommend port forwarding for a custom app unless you understand some of the security loopholes that can exist on a development web server.  But to manage port forwarding go to http://INTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_MODEM and you'll get a management interface for managing your port forwarding settings.  You'll also see your public IP on your router's management UI or by googling "my ip address".

You can map your modem's IP to an official www web domain with a web domain service like GoDaddy.  You can map your internal IPs to internally known web domains by editing /etc/hosts files on the devices on your network.